# How to use Arrays.fill correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I was given the following problem in class today.

Print (show result) of the following arrays:

```
int[ ] a = {2,4,7,10};
int[ ] b = Arrays.fill(a,7);
int[ ] c = Arrays.fill(a,1,3,8);
```

When i punch these lines of code into NetBeans, I get the following error:

```
"incompatible types - required: int[] - found: void"
```

Any ideas on what is not working correctly?

Comment: Have a look at [the Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int[],%20int%29) and it will be quite clear what's going on.  Btw, Javadoc is quickly accessible in Netbeans via rightclick or alt-f1 on any standard classname or method.  Learn to use the Javadoc properly, it will save you lots of time and frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Arrays#fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) has a `void` return type, simply use

```
Arrays.fill(a,7);
```

Answer (score 6):

[`Arrays#fill()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) doesn't return the array. It has `void` return type. Just use:

```
int[] a = {2,4,7,10};
Arrays.fill(a,7);
Arrays.fill(a,1,3,8);
```

Comment: Should i be getting the following outputs after each line if i use a println after each of the three statements?
    [2, 4, 7, 10]
    [7, 7, 7, 7]
    [7, 8, 8, 7]

Comment: @user2856289 Yes. You can print the array after each fill, to see the difference.